# sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23

Tags: python-3.x, text-mining

Estoy tratando de clasificar texto en español: 
usando:
https://github.com/aylliote/senti-py

Primero instalo la librería, ejecuto en la línea de comandos:

```
pip install spanish_sentiment_analysis
```

Luego al ejecutar miarchivo.py:

```
from classifier import *
#las siguientes líneas son irrelevantes, ya que se cae en la primera
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23

Error completo:

> c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib__init__.py:15:
>   DeprecationWarning: sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and
>   will be removed in 0.23. Please import this functionality directly
>   from joblib, which can be installed with: pip install joblib. If this
>   warning is raised when loading pickled models, you may need to
>   re-serialize those models with scikit-learn 0.21+.
>   warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)

He intentado corregir instalando:

```
pip install joblib
```

Pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Favor su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que es un error?, ya que parece más bien un warning que no debiera impedirte seguir ejecutando el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero de todo como dice @Patricio Moracho . **Es un Warning, no un error**, por lo que por ahora puedes seguir adelante, si es verdad que en el futuro, como indica el warning, probablemente no te funcione, cuando SKlearn haga más actualizaciones de su biblioteca.

Lo que sucede es que estás usando un paquete que no ha sido actualizado recientemente y que no tiene un gran desarrollo `spanish_sentiment_analysis`. En este caso lo que te ocurre es que ese paquete utiliza otros paquetes (como casi todos), y estos paquetes se han ido actualizando, pero `spanish_sentiment_analysis` no.

El paquete `spanish_sentiment_analysis` **está utilizando `SKlearn` en una versión más desactualizada** de la que tu tienes. Por ejemplo el paquete fue construido en `scickit-learn 0.19` y tú tienes instalado la versión `scickit-learn 0.22`.

### Soluciones al problema

1. Hacer un downgrade a la versión que utiliza el modulo `spanish_sentiment_analysis` usando `pip install scikit-learn==0.XX` o usando conda `conda install scikit-learn==0.XX` donde XX es el número de versión que utiliza el paquete.
2. Ir exactamente a las funciónes dentro del paquete `spanish_sentiment_analysis` que está importando y usando `sklearn.externals.joblib` y sus funciones y modificarlo por las del paquete `joblib`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alberto, me quedó bastante claro, tendré las consideraciones al respecto para que no quede mi código obsoleto.

Comment: De nada @RenéSilva :)